# Showing that average velocity equals change in position over change in time

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

It is frequently stated that average velocity equals the displacement divided by the time increment over which this displacement occurred. I have two questions:

1. How is this quantity the average? How would one go about showing that the displacement divided by the time increment over which this displacement occurred is the same as summing the constituent velocities and dividing by the number of different velocities (i.e. just taking the arithmetic mean)?
2. If I say velocity changes over time according to $v(t)=t^2$ and position changes over time according to $x(t)=t^3/3$, and I want the average velocity over the time interval $[0,2]$, using the average velocity formula I would think average velocity = $((2^3/3)-0)/2-0 = 4/3$. Then I go to the velocity function and see that the velocity starts at $0$ at $t=0$ and is $4$ at $t=2$. How does it make sense that the average velocity here is $4/3$?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the change in position as $\Delta x$, then it is true that the average velocity would be your total distance traveled $\Delta x$ over time $t$ just by definitions. However I see a calculus tag so I am going to assume you are familiar with integrals. Recall that average value of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is given by $$f_{avg} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx.$$ Now when you want to find the velocity given a distance function $s(t)$, we take the derivative and thus $v(t)=s'(t)$. Moreover, the average velocity over the time interval $[a,b]$ is as follows:
$$V_{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int\limits_a^b v(x)dx\\
=\frac{1}{b-a}[s(b)-s(a)].$$

I hope this helps and encourage you to work out any details you are missing.